# Gender of most recent loanwords from English?

Tags: anglais, genre, emprunts

I've been told that most recent loanwords from English are masculine (e.g., week-end, show, internet, muffin, software, match, sweepstake, blog): could someone please provide a reputable reference substantiating this claim? In particular, and as an example, is the gender of "Facebook" and "Bitcoin" masculine? Finally, are there many notable exceptions to the assignment of male gender (such as the word "la star")?

Comment: *Facebook* is a company name and (I just realized that now) they don't really have genders in French as they are never used with an article. I guess the rare agreements would be masculine though. And *un bitcoin* is largely predominant, even though the (not quite befitting) underlying noun *pièce* is feminine.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez “Mon facebook” is still uncommon, but gaining popularity, to mean “my Facebook profile page”. I think it's always masculine.

Comment: For "software" there is the French word "logiciel(le)" which is both adjective and substantive. The substantive is used in its masculine form "un logiciel".

Comment: I tried to find counterexamples and for now I only found words used in both feminine and masculine forms: ["battle"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_%28rap%29) and ["flashmob"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/flashmob).

Comment: "J'ai un facebook" is not really correct (but often used), what people want to say is "J'ai un compte sur facebook". So it doesn't apply here for facebook, but the gender would be masculine.

Comment: I just accidentally found that [interface](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/interface) is feminine (although, according to Wiktionary, it's often used as a masculine word).

Comment: Please note _week-end_, _show_, _muffin_, _match_, and _sweepstake_ are not "most recent"; _muffin_ was in Balzac; Voltaire and Chateaubriand wrote _show_, many are 100 years old+. Star was attested masc. before fem. Note with a brand like _Coca-cola_ you had hesitations, the feminine (une) worked for some time (Étiemble liked it). Cf. individual entries [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/star). Thanks.

Comment: Quite recently, a colleague of mine remarked that this might be regional, but all loanwords in IT (socket, thread, log) are often used as feminine words where I work (Luxembourg), though I have the habit of using them in a masculine form (except for socket, but this might be due to the fact that it is pronounced like [_socquette_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/socquette)).

Comment: P.S. Of course every noun has a gender, proper name or not. "Je trouve que NOM est ADJ." That adjective is either masculine or feminine :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a quite comprehensive list on the wiktionnaire https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Mots_fran%C3%A7ais_d%E2%80%99origine_anglaise and it is a fact that nearly all the loanwords from English to French are masculine.
Note that words that are not modified (francisés) seem to all be masculine. There are very few exceptions otherwise and they are often obvious: **la/le** *babysitter*, **la** *pompom girl*, **la** *miss* or with a spelling that make them sound like a French word: [la fission](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/fission) (sounds like *mission*, *session*, *dépression*...), **une** *overdose* (**la** dose in French), **une** *motion*, **la** *randomisation*, **la** *standing ovation* (**une** *attention*, **une** *émotion*...).

@SGimenez mentioned two more exceptions in his comment, which are not included in the rules : **la** *start-up* (une société) and **la** *soul* (une musique). And I would add **la** *rocking-chair* (une chaise) to this list of exception, as well as **la** *star* and **la** *battle* mentioned earlier.

Comment: Haven't been through the full list but I noticed *overdose* which is not so surprisingly feminine given the ending and the gender of *dose* in French. I also guess that *sex-symbol* is commonly used with both genders. And *soul* which is feminine in French because of *musique*. Also *start-up* because of *société*.

Comment: merci pour le commentaire: j'ai ajouté vos exceptions.

Comment: Je serais curieux de savoir d'où vient le féminin de soul. Les autres musiques sont au masculin (LE rock, LE gospel, LE blues, ...)

Comment: sans doute parce que c'est bien de la "soul music" comme on dit de LA pop, parce que music est sous-entendu. Dans LE rock, on ne sous-entend pas music: j'ai jamais entendu "rock music", "blues music" etc.

Comment: @Arthur ça se tient, je n'avais pas pensé à la pop. Merci!

Comment: @Arthur potentiellement par le fait que _soul_ veuille dire _âme_ qui est féminin, comme la star, on garde le genre de l'équivalent en Français ?

Comment: @Tensibai Why not mais pourquoi *la* pop?

Answer (score 3):

Reddit features many more posts on this subject, too numerous to be reproduced here, but I just quote a few comments [from this chain](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/1d9p48/when_a_new_word_is_created_how_is_its_gender/):

---

[Permanent_throwaway1  25 points 2 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/1d9p48/when_a_new_word_is_created_how_is_its_gender/c9oa1jh)

In French if a word is borrowed directly from English (un anglicisme) it will be masculine. If the borrowed word is changed to a frenchified spelling and pronunciation, it could be masculine or feminine based on the spelling or what have you. For example, all words in French that end in -tion, -sion, -ure, and -ité are feminine. La torsion, la structure, la fraternité.

[Choosing_is_a_sin Lexicography | Sociolinguistics | French 1 point 2 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/1d9p48/when_a_new_word_is_created_how_is_its_gender/c9pbynn)

> I'm going to have to disagree here. There is a strong tendency in French to assign masculine gender to borrowings from languages without gender. With the exception of some well-established anglicisms in Quebec French, the only time we seem to find feminine borrowings is when there is a corresponding native feminine [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_%28psycholinguistics%29). I can't think of any recent French borrowings that fill a semantic gap (i.e. whose denotatum had no word for it, e.g. le sushi, le zouk) that are feminine.